# CMake built program does not show console

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, wolfram-mathematica

I am creating a plugin executable that is installed in another program (in this case it is a Mathematica plugin that will be installed into Mathematica, but I am not sure if this matters).

I created the project using CMake. However, in the past, when I would create this program, a console was shown. Now, I cannot get the console to show up anymore, which makes debugging really hard.

I've read about the `-mwindows` flag, which should do the opposite (i.e. *hide* the console window), but using this flag leads to:

> g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-mwindows’".

For the rest, I cannot find anything related to Linux (just about any post I can find is about *hiding* the console window on *Windows*).

Where do I look further, or how do I make this window show up?

System:

- Linux Mint 21.3 (MATE)
- GCC 11.4.0
- Mathematica 14.0

Comment: I don't think Linux has a concept of automatically opening a terminal window when a program starts. That's a Windows thing (where it's configured at link time via `-mwindows`). You can try running the whole Mathematica from a terminal, maybe your output will be printed there too.

Comment: Yes! that did the trick. I was under the illusion that I had it working originally on Linux as well, but perhaps I have confused from back in the day that I was using Windows. Thanks for your answer, this is what I needed. Don't know how I can mark the question as answered right now.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as a solution, only an answer can be marked. You can write your answer and mark it, or delete the question if you want.

Comment: To get a console in Linux, you generally do <ctrl><alt>F<n> where F<n> is function key, typically f2 thru f6.  But you don't want a console.  You just want a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77992692/cmake-built-program-does-not-show-console-linux-gcc/77994639#comment137496983_77992692):

> I don't think Linux has a concept of automatically opening a terminal window when a program starts. That's a Windows thing (where it's configured at link time via `-mwindows`). You can try running the whole Mathematica from a terminal, maybe your output will be printed there too.

Using that, I managed to get my output the way I wanted. I think my memory got clouded over the course of time, perhaps I only automatically saw the console on Windows. Anyway, starting Mathematica from the terminal does show the output.

Answer (score -1):

`-mwindows` flag is useful only for cross-compiling the programs for Windows with MinGW in Linux. In your case the only way to do is to run the terminal GUI (`gnome-terminal` in Mint) with the proper wrapper script in bash to run also the shell containing your building environment, the hoster application, and then your program.